# checking most CPU usage/ time based on request (Azure appservice/ application insights)

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an application installed on the Azure app service and I have auto scaling set up so when CPU usage is above 75% it scales out.

I am reaching 10 instances on the node some times so I want to be able to optimize the code, but just blindly optimizing stuff is not efficient. How can I check max CPU usage and total based on the requests?

- I can see the duration on the requests when I look at application insights, but it is not quite what I want since some of the requests call blob storage and the call is taking long, but since it is Async call, it will release the thread and thus shouldn't have an impact on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about profiler options for app service.

One possible way is to try to simulate load locally and then profile (with profiler from Visual Studio or dotTrace from JetBrains).

If it is hard to simulate the load then maybe setup one VM with the same web site and distribute some traffic their using Traffic Manager. Then again use profiler.

Application Insights Service Profiler is more suited for profiling latencies (for instance, which dependencies took the most time, or whether code was blocked on some mutex) than CPU. Profiling CPU is quite different effort, which includes information about how garbage collector is doing, etc.